# Outlook email attachments with duplicate names, how to save by attachment number?

Tags: outlook, email-attachments

There seem to be many descriptions online about attachments with duplicate names.  When you have a *lot* of attachments, it's not practical to manually save each one to a different name.  It's also prone to manual error.

There are many code snippets for automating the saving of attachments, but I hunted for through quite few and experimented with VBA code snippets before assembling a complete subroutine.  Hoping that my answer posted below will save someone an afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is VBA code that does what is needed:

```
Public Sub svAttachByIndx(Folder As String)                               
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")                   
   For Each Atchmt In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Attachments 
     FilePath = Folder & "\" & Format(Atchmt.Index, "00.") & _            
                fso.GetExtensionName(Atchmt.FileName)                     
      Debug.Print FilePath                                                
      Atchmt.SaveAsFile FilePath                                          
   Next                                                                   
End Sub
```

The VBA editor is opened from Outlook using `Alt+F11`.  To use the above subroutine, select the message containing the attachments of interest, open the Immediate Window in the VBA editor (`Ctrl+G`), and enter:

```
Call svAttachByIndx("C:\User\Your.User.Name\Path\to\desired\folder")
```